# Fixed points free automorphisms of Teichmüller spaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathcal{T}_{g,n}$ be the Teichmüller space of a compact oriented surface of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points. Assume that $N:=3g-3+n>0$. Viewing $\mathcal{T}_{g,n}$ as a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}^N$ via the Bers embedding, the mapping class group acts on $\mathcal{T}_{g,n}$ as holomorphic automorphisms of $\mathcal{T}_{g,n}$.

Is there always a fixed points free automorphism of $\mathcal{T}_{g,n}$?

Comment: A mapping class fixes a point in Teichmuller space precisely when it is an automorphism of the corresponding Riemann surface, and thus has finite order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  In a bit more detail: if the Teichmüller space has positive dimension then the given topological surface admits a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism. (This is an exercise, but perhaps a non-trivial one, depending on your background.) A pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism induces a fixed-point-free isomorphism of the Teichmüller space.

**Edit:** As Andy [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464370/fixed-points-free-automorphisms-of-teichmuller-spaces#comment1206006_464372), any Dehn twist (about an essential simple closed curve) also gives an example.

Comment: There is no need for a pseudo Anosov.  A Dehn twist also has no fixed points.  Pseudo Anosovs are needed for the stronger property of having positive translation distance.

Comment: Many apologies for asking such a trivial question. I was thinking about a generalization of Cartan's theorem for Teichmuller spaces. The classical Cartan theorem asserts that a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^k$ has a noncompact automorphism group if and only if there are a point $x \in \Omega$,  a point $p \in \partial \Omega$ and a sequence $\{\phi_i\}_i$ of automorphisms of $\Omega$ such that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \phi_i(x)=p$. Now the question is the following: Can we choose the sequence of automorphisms as the iterates of a single automorphism?

Comment: I was thinking from the several complex variables viewpoint. I completely forgot about the mapping class group side.

Comment: @MahdiTeymuriGarakani - well, in the case of Teichmüller space, the answer is “yes you can use iterates”.  I can’t help you with the general case. Sorry!

Comment: @LSpice - Thank you for the edition.

Comment: @SamNead -Thanks for the answer. Yes it is trivial for Teichmuller spaces . In generel, I don't know.

Comment: @AndyPutman -Thank you for your answers.